# Using laplace transform method (RLC) Circuit

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, laplace-method

So I been stuck in this problem for quite a while
The current I(t) in a series circuit RLC is ruled by initial value:

$$I''(t)+2I'(t)+2I(t)=g(t), \ \ I(0)=10; I'(0)=0$$

where
$$g(t)={(20;  0< t< 3 \pi),(0; 3\pi \le t  < 4\pi),(20;4pi<t):}$$

What i know for the most part is that it uses Laplace Transform.

Comment: I have corrected a little your text, which was un-readable. Please learn the basics of Latex...

Comment: I'm not a moderator, but I think you are supposed to show some attempt to solve the problem. Anyway, a couple of comments. 1. Check those intervals because they don't look dimensionally correct. It should be $T_1=\frac{3π}{ω}$ and the same for $T_2$ 2. $g(t)$ can be expressed as the sum of three step functions: $20\,\text{H}(t)$, $-20\,\text{H}\left(t-\frac{3π}{ω}\right)$ and $20\,\text{H}\left(t-\frac{4π}{ω}\right)$.